# Create table with distinct values based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I have a table which fills up with lots of transactions monthly, like below.

```
Name          ID        Date         OtherColumn
_________________________________________________
John Smith    11111     2012-11-29   Somevalue
John Smith    11111     2012-11-30   Somevalue
Adam Gray     22222     2012-12-11   Somevalue
Tim Blue      33333     2012-12-15   Somevalue
John NewName  11111     2013-01-01   Somevalue
Adam Gray     22222     2013-01-02   Somevalue
```

From this table i want to create a dimension table with the unique names and id's. The problem is that a person can change his/her name, like "John" in the example above. The Id's are otherwise always unique. In those cases I want to only use the newest name (the one with the latest date).

So that I end up with a table like this:

```
Name          ID
______________________
John NewName  11111
Adam Gray     22222
Tim Blue      33333
```

How do I go about achieving this?
Can I do it in a single query?

Comment: Are John Smith and John NewName the same person? Do you want to keep a historical record of all names of User `11111` including John Smith or do you only need John NewName?

Comment: @kush he says pretty clearly he wants the newest name per ID value

Comment: Sporki, How do I know that "John NewName" is newer then "John Smith"? Is it because "John NewName" was the latest entry with ID = 11111 in the top table you show?

Comment: @deblendewim The OP says: *"I want to only use the newest name (**the one with the latest date**)."*

Comment: @deblendewim yes, the Id is always unique to one person.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE for this.  It simplifies ranking and window functions.

```
;WITH CTE as
(SELECT
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] DESC),
  ID,
  Name
 FROM
  YourTable)
SELECT
  Name,
  ID
FROM
  CTE
WHERE
  RN = 1
```

Comment: should the CTE not have a `FROM` section ?

Comment: @whytheq It definitely should!  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a table is a bad idea, but this is how you get the most recent name.

```
select name
from yourtable yt join 
(select id, max(date) maxdate
from yourtable
group by id ) temp on temp.id = yt.id and yt.date = maxdate
```

Comment: ...and this will make some dupes if he has two values for the same name on the same date.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? I think your solution is a good one. It's just missing `ID` in the select clause.

Comment: @JNK, can't he then just do `select name, DISTINCT(ID) from...`?

Comment: @Hudon yes he can add a `DISTINCT` but now we are getting into the territory of extreme inefficiency.  It will work but it's not an optimal method.

Answer (score 0):

JNK's `CTE` solution is an equivalent of the following.

```
SELECT
  Name,
  ID
FROM (
     SELECT
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] DESC),
      Name, 
      ID
     FROM theTable
     )
WHERE RN = 1
```

Trying to think a way to get rid of the partition function without introducing the possible duplicates.